# How to sort a list from queryset using Django

Tags: python, django, list, sorting, django-queryset

I want to sort a list converted from queryset. I've tried using `sorted`, but I'm getting an error

This is my code:

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def practiceAnswer_filter(request):
    # GET list of filtered practiceAnswer
    if request.method == 'GET':
        practiceAnswers = PracticeAnswer.objects.all()
        
    practice_id = request.GET.get('practice_id', None)
    if practice_id is not None:
        # filter practiceAnswer based on practice_id
        practiceAnswer_filtered = practiceAnswers.filter(practice_id__practice_id__icontains=practice_id)
        # convert queryset to list
        practiceAnswer_list = list(practiceAnswer_filtered)
        # shuffle to get random practiceAnswer
        shuffle(practiceAnswer_list)
        # splice list to limit practiceAnswer
        practiceAnswer_shuffled = practiceAnswer_list[:3]
        
        practiceAnswer_sort = practiceAnswer_shuffled
        dict(sorted(practiceAnswer_sort.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
        print(practiceAnswer_sort)
        
        practiceAnswers_serializer = PracticeAnswerSerializer(practiceAnswer_sort, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(practiceAnswers_serializer.data, safe=False)
```

This is the original data from queryset :

```
<QuerySet [<PracticeAnswer: 1>, <PracticeAnswer: 2>, <PracticeAnswer: 3>]>
```

This is the converted data from queryset to list :

```
[<PracticeAnswer: 1>, <PracticeAnswer: 2>, <PracticeAnswer: 3>]
```

Actually with the original data and converted data I already got the sorted data but from the original data I still process it by filtering it based on `practice_id` and randomizing the data to get random data after that limiting / splice to display only 3 data. Without `sorted` the 3 data that appear are not sequential, I want the data to be sorted by the values 1, 2, 3

If I run code above, I got an error :

```
AttributeError at /api/practice-answer-filter
'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

How to fix it?
I have no idea what to do.
Please help me.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `.sort` like that:

```
def sort_list(e):
    return e.pk


practiceAnswer_shuffled.sort(key=sort_list)
```

[More info about sort](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_sort.asp)